# Salesforce Bulkv2.0 job failed with error message: Failure writing to File store

Tags: bulk-api, upsert

I executed a bulk job using the Salesforce Bulkv2 API. 
Operation: Upsert
Status: Failed
State Message: Failure writing to File store

I can't find information on this error and am wondering what might have caused it.

[image: Screenshot]